# How to use question alert using sweetalert in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a problem using sweetalert in Laravel
how to make a confirmation alert using `Alert::question` to delete data in the table?
this is my code, but the alert appear after the data was deleted, how to fix this problem?

```
public function delete($id)
    {Alert::question('Benar Ingin Hapus data?','data tidak dapat dikembalikan')->persistent('Close');
        DB::table('daftar_pelanggans')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back();}
```

this is the delete button view.blade

```
   <td>
       <a href="{{ url('pages/daftar_pelanggan/edit/'.$pelanggan->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> 
 <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <a href="{{ url('daftar_pelanggan/delete/'.$pelanggan->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
     </td>
```

this is the routing web.php

```
Route::get('daftar_pelanggan/delete/{id}', [DaftarPelangganController::class,'delete'])->name('daftar_pelanggan.delete');
```

output :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript code on the page that have the delete button/link to handle it(not PHP code).

an example use onclick on you delete link

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" action="{{ url('daftar_pelanggan/delete/'.$pelanggan->id) }}" onclick="deleteData(this)"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
```

then add below code to the bottom of your blade/view after sweetalert js.

```
    function destroyData(link) {
        swal({
            icon: 'warning',
            title: 'Benar Ingin Hapus data?',
            text: 'data tidak dapat dikembalikan',
            buttons: ["No", "Yes"],
            dangerMode: true,
        })
            .then(isClose => {
                if (isClose) {
                    window.location = $(link).attr('action');
                } else {
                    swal("Delete data canceled");
                }
            });
    }
```

dont forget to change `href` attribute to `action` or another attribute name to prevent auto redirect go to href value after click.

Comment: Thank you, but your code not working for the cancel button, I have been solved for my problem, thank you for your answer